# Multiple column values into a single column as comma separated value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `CommentsTable` with columns like, `CommentA, CommentB, CommentC, CommentD, CommentE`.

All comments columns are `VARCHAR (200)`, by default all columns are `NULL` also.

The data looks like:

```
CommentId   CommentA    CommentB    CommentC    CommentD    CommentE
---------------------------------------------------------------------
12345       NULL        C 001       C 002       NULL        C 003
45678       C 005       NULL        NULL        C 007       NULL
67890       C 010       NULL        C 011       C 012       NULL
36912       C 021       C 023       C 024       C 025       C 026
```

I need to avoid the null values and the remaining values are concatenate with `comma`.

So, the expected output like:

```
CommentId    CommetDetails
-------------------------------
12345        C 001, C 002, C 003
45678        C 005, C 007
67890        C 010, C 011, C 012
36912        C 021, C 023, C 024, C 025, C 026
```

I tried with simple query:

```
SELECT CommentId, ISNULL(CommentA, '') + ', ' + ISNULL(CommentB, '') + ', ' + 
       ISNULL(CommentC, '') + ', ' + ISNULL(CommentD, '') + ', ' +
       ISNULL(CommentE, '') [CommentDetails]
FROM CommentsTable
WHERE ...... --Some conditions
```

But the unwanted `comma` are occurred, So added `IIF`

```
SELECT CommentId, 
       IIF(ISNULL(CommentA, '') <> '', (CommentA + ', '), '') +
       IIF(ISNULL(CommentB, '') <> '', (CommentB + ', '), '') +
       IIF(ISNULL(CommentC, '') <> '', (CommentC + ', '), '') +
       IIF(ISNULL(CommentD, '') <> '', (CommentD + ', '), '') +
       ISNULL(CommentE, '') [CommentDetails]
FROM CommentsTable
WHERE ...... --Some conditions
```

But here also, the `comma` occurred in the last position for some cases (If `CommentD, CommetE` are `NULL`.

Is there any way to achieve to solve for all the cases.

[`Sample SQL Fiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/412f0/8)

Comment: update you sql fiddle script with your last example sowing exactly the situation where you have an unwanted comma at the end.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `ISNULL` like this `ISNULL(',' + CommentA, '')` and write your query like this.

```
SELECT CommentId, 
STUFF(
ISNULL(',' + CommentA, '') + 
ISNULL(',' + CommentB, '') + 
ISNULL(',' + CommentC, '') + 
ISNULL(',' + CommentD, '') +
ISNULL(',' + CommentE, ''),1,1,'') as [CommentDetails]
FROM CommentsTable
WHERE ...... //Some conditions
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6e6ddf/2).

Comment: @ZoharPeled need to remove the initial `,`

Comment: @RagingBull - Thanks, I was finishing up mine as well :)

Comment: my suggested solution does not have that need, and produces the [same results...](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6e6ddf/3)

Comment: no it doesn't, the is trailing `,` in your solution in cases where `CommentE` is NULL

Comment: yeah, I see that now. give me a few minutes to see if I can come up with a way to fix that that is different then yours. worst case, I'll delete my suggestion.

Comment: I came up with a [different solution,](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/899cc/4) but it's worse than yours. I've upvoted your answer and deleted mine.

Comment: how to deal if in case a space is there instead of null. can we handle that also?

Comment: you can check if the column has space then change it to NULL and everything else remains the same.
 ISNULL(',' + CASE WHEN CommentA = '' THEN NULL ELSE CommentA END, '') + 
or you can remove the ISNULL and handle everything in case which would be a bit more clean

Answer (score 2):

The above answers are correct and no challenge to the accepted answer but in case some columns have empty string instead of null then below might help. Please don't hesitate for a better approach and correct me if it's wrong.

```
SELECT CommentId, 
STUFF(
ISNULL(',' + CASE WHEN CommentA= '' THEN NULL ELSE CommentA END, '') + 
ISNULL(',' + CASE WHEN CommentB= '' THEN NULL ELSE CommentB END, '') + 
ISNULL(',' + CASE WHEN CommentC= '' THEN NULL ELSE CommentC END, '') + 
ISNULL(',' + CASE WHEN CommentD= '' THEN NULL ELSE CommentD END, '') +
ISNULL(',' + CASE WHEN CommentE= '' THEN NULL ELSE CommentE END, ''),1,1,'') as [CommentDetails]
FROM CommentsTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #test
(
CommentId int,
CommentA nvarchar(200),
CommentB nvarchar(200),
CommentC nvarchar(200),
CommentD nvarchar(200),
CommentE nvarchar(200)

)
insert into #test values(12345,NULL,'C 001','C 002',NULL,'C 003')
insert into #test values(45678,'C 005',NULL,NULL,'C 007',NULL)
insert into #test values(67890,'C 010',NULL,'C 011','C 012',NULL)
insert into #test values(36912,'C 021','C 023','C 024','C 025','C 026')
```

Use This Code:

```
select CommentId,STUFF(ISNULL(','+CommentA,'')+
                       ISNULL(','+CommentB,'')+
                       ISNULL(','+CommentC,'')+
                       ISNULL(','+CommentD,'')+
                        ISNULL(','+CommentE,''),1,1,'') As Comment 
 from #test
 order by CommentId
```